# missing a final step in using the BingMapsRESTToolkit to get a distance

Tags: c#, bing-maps, bing-api

I need to calculate the distance between 2 places, using the BinMapsRESTToolkit that can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BingMapsRESTToolkit/blob/master/Docs/API%20Reference.md#DistanceMatrixRequest).

However, the documentation only lists properties and methods, but there is no example on how to use this.

What I got so far is this

```
async Task<double> CalculateDistanceWithBingAPI(string from, string to, DataRow row)
{
    double Result = 0;

    DistanceMatrixRequest dm = new DistanceMatrixRequest();
    dm.BingMapsKey = Settings.BingKey;
    dm.TravelMode = TravelModeType.Truck;

    dm.Origins = new List<SimpleWaypoint>();
    dm.Destinations = new List<SimpleWaypoint>();

    dm.Origins.Add(new SimpleWaypoint(from));
    dm.Destinations.Add(new SimpleWaypoint(to));

    var x = await dm.Execute();

    //row["Distance"] = dm.??????

    return Result;
}
```

This executes without throwing an exception, but after executing the line `var x = await dm.Execute();` the debugger jumps out of this procedure.

If I call it without the `await` then the variable `x` has a value "not computed yet".

I have no clue how to retrieve the actual distance from the object DistanceMatrixRequest after calling the `Execute()`. It has no events, it has no properties that could hold the info, and it has no usefull documentation

Either I am close but am missing a final step, or I am completely using a wrong approach here, so I could use a little help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `GetEuclideanDistanceMatrix` on your `DistanceMatrixRequest` to get [`DistanceMatrix`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BingMapsRESTToolkit/blob/master/Docs/API%20Reference.md#DistanceMatrix) and then distance should be available via `DistanceMatrix.GetDistance`.

```
DistanceMatrixRequest request = new DistanceMatrixRequest();
// ...
DistanceMatrix matrix = await request.GetEuclideanDistanceMatrix();
double distance = matrix.GetDistance(...);
```